How can I specify liquibase.command.dropAll.requireForce when using Liquibase with Spring Boot?
I'm using Spring Boot 3.3.4 (Liquibase 4.27.0) and noticed that I get these in the logs:
13:33:25.739 I - l.ui INFO: The drop-all command may result in unrecoverable destructive changes to objects at 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres'.
To protect against unwanted drops, set --requireForce=true, which will require a --force=true flag on the command.
Learn more at https://docs.liquibase.com/dropall.

I understand that setting the requireForce would silence this warning (I only need to do a drop all for my tests). But I have been unable to find a way to set this property via Spring Boot.
The only likely possibility I believe is via the spring.liquibase.parameters group in application.yml. However even this doesn't work:
spring:
    liquibase:
        parameters:
            liquibase.command.dropAll.requireForce: true
            liquibase.command.dropAll.force: true

This is possibly because the Liquibase.dropAll method of Liquibase never accesses any custom parameters and seems to work off a hardcoded list of arguments.
CommandScope dropAll = new CommandScope("dropAll")
                    .addArgumentValue(DbUrlConnectionArgumentsCommandStep.DATABASE_ARG, Liquibase.this.getDatabase())
                    .addArgumentValue(DropAllCommandStep.CATALOG_AND_SCHEMAS_ARG, finalSchemas)
                    .addArgumentValue("dropDbclhistory", dropDbclhistory);

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/v4.27.0/liquibase-standard/src/main/java/liquibase/Liquibase.java#L1020-L1023
That means I have no way of specifying this property. What can I do here?

1st Option: Command Line Options
Sub Option 1: Maven
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>
                <argument>--liquibase.command.dropAll.requireForce=true</argument>
                <argument>--liquibase.command.dropAll.force=true</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

Then run the command - mvn spring-boot:run
Sub Option 2: Executable jar
java -Dliquibase.command.dropAll.force=true -Dliquibase.command.dropAll.requireForce=true -jar artifact.jar

2nd Option: Environment Variable
Sub Option 1: Maven
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <environmentVariables>
                <LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_DROP_ALL_FORCE>true</LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_DROP_ALL_FORCE>
                <LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_DROP_ALL_REQUIRE_FORCE>true</LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_DROP_ALL_REQUIRE_FORCE>
            </environmentVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

Then run the command - mvn spring-boot:run
Sub Option 2: Executable jar
java -DLIQUIBASE_COMMAND_DROP_ALL_FORCE=true -DLIQUIBASE_COMMAND_DROP_ALL_REQUIRE_FORCE=true -jar artifact.jar

See if this helps.

Thank you. I was already aware of these approaches and was preferring for a programmatic one. But this answer will definitely help someone else in the same plight as me.
